# failing to load initial value from state

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I am using useEffect to get the image name and then I want to update another state with that state. When I look in console I get a 404 error:

```
http://localhost:8000/uploads/images/%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22local%22%7D%7D
```

Code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getAvatarImage = async () => {
      const response = await Axios.get(
        "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/get-avatar",
        { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token } }
      );
      setAvatar(response.data.avatar);
    };
    if (auth.token) getAvatarImage();
  }, [auth.token]);

 const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState();
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([
    {
      source: avatar,
      options: { type: "local" },
    },
  ]);
```

The FilePond component then uses files to show the file:

```
<FilePond
files={files}
instantUpload={false}
onupdatefiles={setFiles}
allowMultiple={false}
maxFiles={1}
server={{
  load: "http://localhost:8000/uploads/images/",
  process: {
    url: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/update-avatar",
    ondata: (formData) => {
      formData.append("user", auth.userId);
      return formData;
    },
  },
}}
name="image"
labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
/>
```

If I hardcode the image name into 'source', in the files state it works as expected but doesn't work when I use the avatar state variable which makes me think it is something to do with how I am setting the state.

Link to docs if it helps:

https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/frameworks/react/

Comment: A 404 response means your url for your ajax call is wrong or your resource is not where you think it is.

Comment: The path is correct ie: http://localhost:8000/uploads/images but it's the bit after that which is the issue. It should be `da3e4d30-5748-11eb-a3fc-49791bb10b1c.png` but instead it is `%7B"options"%3A%7B"type"%3A"local"%7D%7D`

Comment: Then whatever is building your url is messing it up. It looks like instead of appending the value you expect to the end its appending an object. You are either passing the wrong thing or are missing a property access.

Comment: Hmm. If I console.log(avatar) in the useEffect hook once I `setAvatar` I get what I want which is the image name `da3e4d30-5748-11eb-a3fc-49791bb10b1c.png`. So, I thought that would be correct because if I hardcode that into `source` it works.

Comment: You don't actually show us the relevant code that produces the url but I would wager you are appending `files` to the url when you actually wanted to append `avatar`.

Comment: I can post whatever code you need, I just didn't want to post too much code initially and bog the question down with code. Basically in React I am just making the Axios call to get the image name. That is done in Node.js. I check the user ID and get the image name from the database. I then send that back to the client. So, the `load` bit in filepond is the path to the images and `avatar` is the image name itself. https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/frameworks/react/

Comment: Try posting the code building the URL. I am fairly certain my previous comment is what is happening.

Comment: I will be happy to, but I just don't really understand what you are referring to by `building the URL`? If you could please just clarify that

Comment: In the code loading your image you are probably doing `props.server.load + files` when you should be doing `props.server.load + avatar`

Comment: I think FilePond is handling the load files under the hood. I posted a link a few comments up to their short react documentation (1 pager). If you look at the `<FilePond...` bit of my code you see there it is setting the files from the `files` state.

Comment: If I change the FilePond component `files` prop from `files={files}` to `files={avatar}` then the path is correct but the problem is that it is looking on the frontend instead of the server eg: http://localhost:3000/admin/da3e4d30-5748-11eb-a3fc-49791bb10b1c.png instead of http://localhost:8000/uploads/images/da3e4d30-5748-11eb-a3fc-49791bb10b1c.png

Comment: Ah, I missed the part where filepond was a third party component.  It sort of looks like filepond expects an array of strings instead of objects. This is obviously not what the documentation shows. Are you sure you are on the latest filepond version?

Comment: I think so, I only installed it a few days ago. I am on version 7.1.0

Comment: https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond